# Border around asp templatefield

Tags: asp.net

I am displaying data using gridview. Instead of the typical row/column, I am displaying data in a card view type. Within the `<Column>` tag, I have two `<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">`. These two Templatefileds display data in a side-by-side manner. I would like to draw a single border around both of them. I could draw borders for the individual Templatefields by including a div, but I want a border around both of them.

Thanks

Comment: Showing your HTML/ASPX markup would help. Please show just relevant piece.

Comment: Check the rendered HTML.  Surely there's some element containing the two?  You can apply styling to that element in the CSS.